# Loading CodeIgniter custom libraries

Tags: codeigniter, shared-libraries

I added a simple library/class to my application called Assets. The file is located at:

```
application/libraries/Assets.php
```

The content is:

```
class Assets {

    public function get_images() {
        ....
    }
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('assets');
}
```

And I call it using:

```
public function members() {
    $data = array();
    $data['images'] = $this->assets->get_images();
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Class 'CI_Assets' not found

Filename: ../system/core/Common.php

Line Number: 196
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Some more info: I have a model called Club_model.php and I load that in the controller constructor like: $this->load->model('club_model'); and in that model I have a function called get_clubs... the line that is causing the error is on the database results: foreach ($query->result('Club') as $row) { } ---- if I comment that out the library error above goes away... WTH?

Comment: If I comment out the Assets library mentions the model returns get_clubs() just fine... the two seem to clash. So weird.

Comment: Have you tried ensuring that Assets is upper case in the library load? I had a similar issue with something I did

Comment: What is the name of the filename and class of the controller make sure ucfirst where only the first letter uppercase on class and file name. On controller

Answer (score 0):

Try change class name

```
CI_Assets
```

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. I also tried various different names, thinking Assets could be a reserved work. I tried class Fred, class Baxter etc... nada. Still breaks. It has something to do with the return of my model call.

Comment: I check your code in my CI i works ok, i use CI v 3.1.3, php 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->load->library('Assets'); 
$assets = new Assets();
$assets->get_images();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with the controller and the library both being class Club.